# Python text file updates only when program is shutdown

Tags: python, text-files

I have function that asks input from user and then writes it in the file. However while program is running it does not appear in text file. Which means when I'm trying to read my text file it's empty. If I shutdown my program all of the written text appears into the text file.

I have main function where you choose to read, write or edit notepad. After you choose something main function calls other function. I'm not sure if that is right structure to use in this case or is it bad overall. Hopefully this makes sense.

```python
def new_note():
    file = open('notepad.dat', 'a')
    file.writelines('\n' + input("Write something: "))
    file.writelines(":::" + time.strftime("%X %x"))
    file.close
    main()


def read_file():
    file = open('notepad.dat', 'r')
    notes = [(line.strip()).split() for line in file]
    print(notes)
    file.close
    main()
```

Comment: You aren't actually closing the file - you need brackets to call the method - `file.close()`

Comment: You are only guaranteed that once the file is closed everything will be written. That is because of a writing buffer to the file. If you wish to write immediately to the file you can use `file.flush()` that will flush the buffer immediately to the file even if you didn't close it

Comment: Funny enough I totally forgot those brackets. Everything is working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's more pythonic:

```
def new_note():
    with open('notepad.dat', 'a') as file:
        file.writelines('\n' + input("Write something: "))
        file.writelines(":::" + time.strftime("%X %x"))
    
    main()


def read_file():
    with open('notepad.dat', 'r') as file:
        notes = [(line.strip()).split() for line in file]
        print(notes)       
    
     main()
```

However, it would be helpful is you share the `main` function.
From what I tried on my local system the above didn't seem to cause any issues when omitting the `main()` call.

Comment: This is great, i forgot brackets from `file.close()` but it seems like `with open('notepad.dat', 'a') as file:` also closes file automatically!

Comment: yes, using `with` everything is taken care of for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you wouldn't be able to read your file while trying to write to it at the same time. Also, files will me updated once the file.close is called. Post that the data would appear. You could try restructuring your program.